# How to create ActionResults for Search and Result, cannot figure out

Tags: c#, linq, actionresult

I am trying to create a Search and Result pages. The first `UserTotalTimeSpentReport()` function returns ActionResult which is a Search page. Then, user does some selection and post the page. Then, it will go to the second `UserTotalTimeSpentReport()`, which has `[HttpPost]` tag. In the second `UserTotalTimeSpentReport`, I do a complex LINQ query and produce a result. I dont know how to display that result because it goes the same ActionResult. I need to forward the user to another page. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
public ActionResult UserTotalTimeSpentReport()
{
    UserTotalTimeSpentModel model = new UserTotalTimeSpentModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserTotalTimeSpentReport(string AntsoftCrmUser, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate) 
{
 .....
 .....
 return View(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's another view you mean, then this is the way to go:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserTotalTimeSpentReport(string AntsoftCrmUser, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate) 
{
 .....
 .....
 return View("the name of your view here", result)
}
```

You can read more about the different overloads of the view-method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx)